# Attach Persistent Storage to ECS + Launch Type Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I want to use one persistent storage in cluster, which is being used in all tasks of the services of this cluster. Like in windows, every application has access to "C:/" or "D" storage.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Fargate doesn't support persistent storage natively. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html) please.

So, you can try either:

- Share volumes between containers, but ephemeral storage. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html).
- Use s3 as volume directly mounting a bucket as local storage in the task, using a 3rd party driver like [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). I've used it and it works just fine.
- Use EC2 as launch-type instead of Fargate.